I am getting an InvalidArchiveError in anaconda prompt when I am trying to install tensorflow-gpu. How to solve it?
InvalidArchiveError("Error with archive C:\Users\mrana\AppData\Local\anaconda3\pkgs\tensorflow-base-2.6.0-gpu_py39hb3da07e_0.conda.  You probably need to delete and re-download or re-create this file.  Message was:\n\nfailed with error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\mrana\\AppData\\Local\\anaconda3\\pkgs\\tensorflow-base-2.6.0-gpu_py39hb3da07e_0\\Lib\\site-packages\\tensorflow\\include\\external\\cudnn_frontend_archive\\_virtual_includes\\cudnn_frontend\\third_party\\cudnn_frontend\\include\\cudnn_frontend_EngineConfigGenerator.h'")
I was trying to executing conda install tensorflow-gpu and getting this error.

Did you tried to create a environment and then install tensorflow with pip in the activated env?

The error you're seeing, InvalidArchiveError, indicates a problem with the downloaded archive file of tensorflow-base-2.6.0-gpu_py39hb3da07e_0 within your Anaconda environment. This issue can arise due to factors like interruptions in network connectivity during the download process or corruption of the downloaded file itself.Sometimes, the issue might be due to a corrupted package cache. Clearing the cache and re-downloading the package can often resolve such problems.

Simply retrying the installation might solve the problem if it was caused by a temporary network issue or a glitch during the download process.conda install tensorflow-gpu
